# Comparing Player objects attributes to check who has the shortest name

Tags: java

I want to Compare the names of Player Objects that i have stored in a List.
I have a method which adds Player objects to that list with a name and gender and gives them 2 cards, of 2 different decks

then the method i want to use to compare the names and determine who has the shortest name. But i am kinda stuck and don't know how to fix this.

```
public List<Speler> spelers = new ArrayList<>(); // creating player list



public void VoegSpelerToe(String naam, String geslacht){
        speler = new Speler(naam, geslacht);
        spelers.add(speler);     
        speler.trekKaart(2,schatKaarten);
        speler.trekKaart(2,kerkerKaarten); 
} 

public Speler BeurtSpeler(List<Speler> speler,Comparator<String> comp){
    String shortest = speler.get(0);

    for(Speler str : spelers) {
        if (comp.compare(str, kortste)  <0) {
            kortste = str;
        }
    return shortest;
}
```

Comment: Why don't you use a method speler.getName() to get names and compare each other ?

Comment: Can i like that loop through a list of players?

Comment: Try to code in english ( not dutch ;-) )

Comment: @mahieus i will try to do that :p but it's code for a school project so has to be in dutch -_-

Answer (score 2):

Given the following `Player` class

```
private class Player {
    private String name;

    public Player(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    // #toString omitted
}
```

you can find the player with the shortest name using a custom `Comparator`. The compare method will return `-1` if the length of the name is shorter, `0` if both names have an equal length or `1` is the name is longer than the second one.

#### Java 8

```
private int comparePlayerNameSize(Player player, Player other) {
    if (player.name.length() == other.name.length()) {
        return 0;
    }
    return player.name.length() < other.name.length() ? -1 : 1;
}
```

You can use it like this:

```
players.stream().min(this::comparePlayerNameSize)
            .ifPresent((p) -> /* ... */ ); // do something with the player
```

Full example:

```
Player one = new Player("fooo");
Player two = new Player("foo");
Player three = new Player("bar");

List<Player> players = Arrays.asList(one, two, three);

players.stream().min(this::comparePlayerNameSize)
        .ifPresent(System.out::println);
```

The resulting output is `Player{name='foo'}`.

#### Pre Java 8

If you are not using Java 8, you can use the `Comparator` in the following way:

```
private PlayerNameSizeComparator implements Comparator<Player> {

    @Override
    public int compare(Player p1, Player p2) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

followed by `Collections.min(players, new PlayerNameSizeComparator());`

Full example:

```
Player one = new Player("fooo");
Player two = new Player("foo");
Player three = new Player("bar");

List<Player> players = Arrays.asList(one, two, three);

Player min = Collections.min(players, new PlayerNameSizeComparator());
System.out.println(min);
```

The resulting output is `Player{name='foo'}`.

Please note that `Collections.min()` will throw a `NoSuchElementException` is the collection is empty.

**One final note**: If there are multiple players with the same name length, the first player (according to the element order in the `List`) will be returned with that specific length.

Comment: it seems like i'm not able to call the stream() method

Comment: Check your Java version with cmd and `java --version`. If you are not using Java 8, have a look at the  provided **Pre Java 8** solution.

Comment: oke thank you, how would that exactly work with a List<Player>?

Comment: You mean a complete example with the pre Java-8 style?

Comment: yes because i have created a list and it's always min 3 max 6 players so i need to compare all of those to see who the shortest name has, it's user input btw the names

Comment: Please see my edit. Do you mean that you don´t have players but strings as input?

Comment: no so, i ask the user with how many players he wants to play the game, he enters for example 3. 3 player objects get created and for each of them the user will enter a name and gender this will be stored in the List<Player> players = new ArrayList<>(); so then i want to check who has the shortest name so that player can start the game.

Comment: Then the above exmaple works perfectly for you. Could you explain what you did not understand?

Comment: i don't really get what this does, or what i should add: private PlayerNameSizeComparator implements Comparator<Player> {

    @Override
    public int compare(Player p1, Player p2) {
        // ...
    }
}

Comment: why not `min(Comparator.comparing(Player::getName).reversedOrder())`?

Comment: is that something i'd have to add in the method?

Answer (score 0):

Create a comparator that compares the objects based on the size of the players name (Comparator< Speler>). Then use the Collections.min(..., ...) to get the shortest one.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you have a getName() method for your Speler.

```
public Speler getSpelerWithShortestName(){
   Speler result = null;
   for(Speler sp : spelers){//each spelers from your list
     if(result==null){
        result = sp;
     }
     else{
        if(result.getName().length()>sp.getName().length()){
          result = sp;
        }  
     }
  }
  return result;
}
```